# Reassemble (TCP) Stream using Tshark

Tags: tcp, stream, wireshark, tshark

I have pcaps containing one stream only. I want to reassemble them using tshark, as libnids will fail, e.g.. Libnids fails, as these streams might not have a proper beginning (SYN) and might not have a proper ending (FIN). Therefore, wireshark/tshark is useful. However, i can output the stream content, but how to know whether a packet ended or not? As TCP (and ipv4) is used, the packets are split. But what, if many packets are split successively? So i mean, that all payloads a coming from node2 (which is talking to node1). Therefore, tshark uses a tab before them to show, that its coming from node 2 like this:

```
\t00000000  aa bb cc dd ee ff ....... 
\t00000010  00 11 22 .....
\t00000020  ff ff .. //some new packet
```

But how to identfy, that 00000020 is a new packet? So what i want would be all reassembled, but split payloads like this:

Node2:aabbccddeeff...001122...
Node2:ffff.....

I currently use

```
$ tshark -r name.pcap -z "follow,tcp,hex,0"
```

Thanks for help.